# Rails - ActiveAdmin on Heroku doesn't update Boolean Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, boolean, activeadmin

I've just added a boolean field to a model of a little RoR app of mine, to control activation status of an asset. I'm using ActiveAdmin to generate the Admin interface. Made some local tests and everything went ok. It correctly updated the field as I checked or unchecked the checkbox and pressed 'Update'.

Uploaded the updated application to Heroku, applied the migration which adds the boolean field to my model, restarted the app (just to be sure :) ) logged on ActiveAdmin, updated the boolean field from one table row and: nothing happened. It simply doesn't update the boolean field. If it is false, it stays false and if it is true, it also keeps the value...

Does anyone experienced anything like this and have any tip for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put peace of your code? Is it only the boolean field?

Comment: are you sure you have whitelisted the attribute in AA `params.permit`?

Comment: Shirakia, I had the model working before, but I needed to add this boolean field... 

Yeah Andrey, checked if the update on the file went to heroku but its all there

`permit_params :list, :of, :attributes, :on, :model, :name, :email, :position_id, :status`

Column name is status, the last one

Really don't know what's going on.

Comment: Sorry I mean, do another fields work correctly on Heroku?

Comment: Yes, everything is working normally. Just having problems with this boolean... Gonna keep trying here... Thank you guys!

Comment: can you try changing your update to update!  and tailing the logs?  An error message would be helpful here.

Comment: Guys, don't know why, but after some time it suddenly started working... Don't know if Heroku was experiencing any kind of delay or something... I did not deployed anything the time I made this question and started working on something else... Now I was just going back to this issue and tried once more to save the boolean value and it worked... 

Weird stuff... Thanks for all you help, guys!

Answer (score 1):

I've had this exact problem a couple of times. We found that after we pushed changes to heroku with a boolean ActiveAdmin field and ran a migration, we needed to push a second change (even just an updated comment) to the heroku server again. For some reason forcing heroku to redeploy this way gets it to render the boolean active admin field properly.

Comment: God, I love you. This was driving me crazy!